# CVS check out - Names

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, repository, cvs

(sorry I could not find a title)
it's my first question here, and I trust in you guys!

I recently accidentially made a Project called "Queue" in school, at the end of the lesson I uploaded it to our school's CVS. Later I found out that I used an upper case "Q" and made a new one called "queue".

Today after re-installing eclipse at home I tried to check out the whole project, and couldn't because: "Could not create resource /objekte/src/queue: Problem creating folder: /objekte/src/queue. A resource exists with a different case: '/objekte/src/Queue'."

How can I permanently fix this. AFAIK I cannot delete anything on the repo... :(

Thanks guys!

Comment: Welcome to SO! this resource might be useful to you: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/cvsmanual/Removingdirectories.html

Comment: Welcome aboard! do you have access to the cvs server? if so, maybe change the name of your `Queue` project to something else...

Comment: I have acces, but only to read and create things, not to delete them...